# sed command is not working as supposed

Tags: text, sed, openwrt

I can't wrap my head around a sed command. I have a text file in which I would like to change some values and for that, I am using the following command:

```
sed -i -e 's/Balance=[0]/Balance=[1]/g' syscfg.txt
```

As you can see I want to change value *Balance=[0] to Balance=[1]* but it doesn't happen. What more I tried this command on a test.txt where I have written "bla bla bla" and then I am running same command:

```
sed -i -e 's/bla/1/g' test.txt
```

and then it works.

In the Balance=[0] there are no spaces so I thought it will be treated as a single string, but maybe it is something about the parenthesis[]? I checked plenty of posts and tried different variations of this command but nothing worked.

And I am working on openWrt if that makes any change (Arduino Yun).

Thanks in advance for some tips!

Comment: yeah `[]` are creating issues.. try `\[0\]` .. leave `[1]` alone

Comment: Chances are it's that you're using the regexp metacharacters `[` and `]` incorrectly but [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output otherwise we're just guessing what you need by reading a script that doesn't do what you need. I would bet there's a better solution that's more than just a tweak to your use of `[` and `]`.

Comment: sp asic - hell yeah it was it! Now it works - thanks a lot !

Comment: I will dig up this question a bit, what if I don't know weather the first value is 0 or 1 or 2, etc. I was trying to make variations '*' e.g.: `Balance=\[*\]` But no luck. Any ideas?